# How do I construct a 4x1 MUX using only 2 input NAND Gates?

Tags: multiplexer

I’m trying to create a 4x1 mux using only 2 input one output NAND gates

Comment: This one is pretty easy. What have you tried?

Comment: 11 NANDs is straight-forward to just draw out, by rote. If you show some attempted effort I'll see if I can help out.

Comment: Best shot at this: try deducing the logical equation and implement it with gates and then convert it all to NAND. Pretty long, but works every time. I guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest an obvious start:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGlJzbm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above has four inputs, \$A\$, \$B\$, \$C\$, and \$D\$, plus two inputs representing a binary value used to select among them (\$S_0\$ and \$S_1\$.) Now, you somehow need to apply \$S_0\$ and \$S_1\$ to these (and additional) NAND gates in order to reach \$F_0\$. Does the above suggest any thoughts about how to proceed from here?

---

Here's one possible next step:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPlpQrm.png)</sup>

I've used \$S_1\$ (the higher order binary selection value bit) to select (or activate) the appropriate pairs of NAND gates. Note that if \$S_1=0\$ then \$A\$ and \$B\$ are enabled and that if \$S_1=1\$ then \$C\$ and \$D\$ are enabled.

How might you then select between what remains?

---

Here's another possible next step:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYISbZm.png)</sup>

I've used \$S_0\$ (the lower order binary selection value bit) to select (or activate) the appropriate pairs of NAND gates. Note that if \$S_0=0\$ then \$A\$ and \$C\$ are enabled and that if \$S_0=1\$ then \$B\$ and \$D\$ are enabled.

How might you then select between what remains?

---

Enough time has gone by (a few days since asked.) I'll complete this for others who may come upon it and want to see the results.

Continuing from the first starting point I'd mentioned earlier, the result is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f49INU.png)</sup>

And continuing from the second starting point I'd mentioned earlier, the result is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVAYDQ.png)</sup>

---

That's it.

Answer (score -1):

[image: The tree of creating 4:1 MUX using 2 input NAND gates]
Here, we see how we divide and conquer the problem. 
We first build a 4:1 mux using three 2:1 mux and in turn show a 2:1 mux using 2 input NAND gates

Hope this helps!

Comment: Invertor is actually another nand with one input tied high. and the inverter on S1 is not needed, either that or switch D0 and D1. I think you have S0 and S1 backwards too.